# AngularJS ui typehead not working with http

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I've been trying to make the AngularJS ui typehead work with my backend but had no success.

In my partial:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="language.id as language.name for language in getLanguages($viewValue) | filter:$viewValue"/>
```

In my controller:

```
$scope.getLanguages = function(search) {
  // This works:
  return [{"id":"15","name":"Norwegian (Bokm\u00e5l)","short":"no"},{"id":"45","name":"Norwegian (Nynorsk)","short":"nn"}];

  // This doesn't work:
  return $http.get('/json/suggest/languages/' + search).success(function(response) {
    return response;
  });
}
```

As you can see it works when I define the response statically in JS but not when it's retrieved from backend. The static response is copy-pasted from backend response. Http request is working, I can see the response in developer tools, format is correct but typehead doesn't appear. Any idea why this happens?

Btw, I've used this Plunker as an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/eGG9Kj?p=preview

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code:

- you are using `success` which does *not* return a promise, change it to `then` instead;
- after the above change you need to return data only instead of the whole `response`.

Change your code like so:

```
return $http.get('/json/suggest/languages/' + search).then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You're expecting `$http.get` to return the value synchronously. AFAIK that's not how it works. Here's what I would do:

```
$scope.languages = [];

$scope.getLanguages = function(search) {
    $http.get('/json/suggest/languages/' + search).success(function(response) {
        $scope.languages = response;
    }
}
```

Then you would need to bind the typeahead to `$scope.languages` and figure out how to call `getLanguages` as you type - probably need some sort of directive there.

Comment: I'd suggest you to put this in an Angular Service.

Comment: @AngelinSirbu this is *not* a correct answer - although it could work it is not a proper solution in this case as it forces you to manually resolve promises - something that is not needed with the typeahead directive. Please amend or I will be obliged to down-vote.